# Can I report phone numbers as spam callers?

Tags: phone-app, spam

Google recently introduced a feature that lets me know if someone is a suspected spam caller. However, sometimes I get calls from numbers that aren't listed as spam callers but are still spam callers. Is there some way I can report these?

[image: Screenshot of spam call]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can report callers as spam.

From [Google support](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3459196):

> You can mark all calls from a number as spam to keep from getting any more and to report the spammer.
>
> 1. Open your device's Phone app phone.
> 2. Go to Recent calls Recents.
> 3. Tap the call you want to report as spam.
> 4. Tap Block / report spam. You’ll be asked if you want to block the number.
> 5. If you have the option, tap Report call as spam.
> 6. Tap Block.