# How can I report a spam phone number, without blocking it? Stock android

Tags: calls, stock-android, spam

Every spam call I get is from a different "burner" number.  Android asks me if I wish to "block and report" the number. I wish to report it, but not block it, as it may be a spoofed number from someone who I will eventually wish to hear from.

Is there a way to "report" only?

See also [Can I report phone numbers as NOT spam callers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179400/can-i-report-phone-numbers-as-not-spam-callers)
And https://www.nomorobo.com/

My particular phone is "stock google pixel" but answers for any version of android are welcome.

Comment: What country are you in? And who do you want to report the number to?

Answer (score 2):

1. Block and Report
2. Unblock

So it is reported but not blocked anymore!

Comment: Creative.  But effective?  Depends on how Google's algorithms work, if it clears the spam count when the number is unblocked.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I've been doing the same as @mohsyn recommended. I learned today that **it is completely ineffective**. According to https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9061432, "Unblocking a conversation removes a spam report."

Comment: @KevinHigby OP asked for android contacts and not google mail. Link you shared is for google emails. 
Android blocks numbers locally but reports on server. So when you report and then unblock it would be counted as reported and will not be blocked on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and up until recently I've been doing the same as @mohsyn recommended. However, according to https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9061432, "**Unblocking a conversation removes a spam report.**"

So, to answer your question, it is currently **not possible** to report a spam number without also blocking it, since undoing the block also undoes the spam report.

Also, in response to @mohsyn (I still can't comment): the link I shared is for the "stock" Android Messages app. I have a Google Pixel phone like OP.

Answer (score -1):

> Every spam call I get is from a different "burner" number

Its probably not. Most probably the number is spoofed.

In either case, there is not much you can do. In New Zealand, there is a Government organisation, that you report this to. But again, theres not much they can do, except to put it into a database.

I think its highly improbable that the same number will be used by a genuine caller in the future. These numbers are often not valid. The ones I see are too long. So you can block them, but there is no benefit to it.

In short, don't stress and ignore it. If I can't recognise a number and I am not expecting a call, I usually don't answer. If its genuine, they will either leave a message or call again.

Most of the spammers have it automated. The computer calls random numbers  or from a list purchased on the dark web. If you answer, it gets transferred to a person. And now they know its a valid number. It then gets added to a list.